# Разновидности return в JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Есть :

1. `return;`
2. `return false;`
3. `return (false);`

в чем разница ?

Comment: первый возвращает _undefined_, второй и третий - _false_

Answer (score 5):

При использовании первого функция вернет `undefined`.
второй и третий эквивалентны и при их использовании функция вернет `false`

Comment: благодарю за пояснение

Comment: но в любом из случаев , функция не  будет продолжать работу ?

Comment: @SarkisAllahverdian, да, после выполнения оператора `return` производится выход из функции и код который расположен после это оператора выполнен не будет

Comment: любопытно, а мне за такой же ответ влепили 2 минуса.

Answer (score 2):

> Это новый ответ на [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/846086/%D0%9D%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%87%D1%91%D1%82-return-%D0%B2-js#846086), отмеченный дубликатом данного.
>   Ответ предназначен для чтения участником [@Mark Minerov](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/297258/mark-minerov).

Смотрите. Предположим, вы пишете функцию. И вы хотите, чтобы она возвращала какое-то значение. Например, как функция `input`. Её можно вставить в другую функцию, записать в переменную или массив. Но, скажем, функцию `print` — нет, так как она ничего не возвращает. Вот пример использования (взял с другого сайта):

Данная функция возвращает квадрат аргумента `X`, где `X` — число.

```
function square(x) {
  return x * x;
}
```

Comment: Лучше его там и написать, а тут - удалить.

Comment: @Qwertiy На тот момент когда я это писал, вопрос был закрыт. Сейчас не вижу смысла переносить. (т.к. ответ уже получен от других пользователей, а удалять здесь тоже не нужно)