# Как использовать return в JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Расскажите мне про функцию `return` как для ребёнка, я не могу понять как её использовать в JavaScript.

Comment: Вопрос шире, чем предложенный дубликат [Разновидности return в JavaScript](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/477676/%d0%a0%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%b4%d0%bd%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8-return-%d0%b2-javascript), поэтому переоткрываю. Очевидно же, что можно возвращать не только «ничего» или `false`.

Comment: В хорошем ответе должны быть примеры кода с описанием, что каждый пример делает и чем отличается.

Comment: Раз просите рассказать «как для ребёнка» то наверное уже что-то читали про return и что-то не поняли. Полезно будет изложить какое описание return Вы нашли и что именно в нем непонятно. Так отвечающему будет ясно с чего начинать (знаете ли Вы что такое программирование; что такое JavaScript; что такое функции и для чего они используются), какие моменты нужно уточнить и на чем заострить внимание.

Comment: А знаю что такое функции, знаю что такое переменные, могу использовать функции и т.д., знаю PHP, я уже достаточно знаю в JS, но и с PHP тоже не понимаю про return

Answer (score 6):

1. Это не функция, а конструкция языка.
2. Функция в JS обязана что-то вернуть. Даже без `return` будет возвращено `undefined`.
   А если нужно вернуть что-то осмысленное, то с помощью этого оператора можно это реализовать, сказав интерпретатору что именно надо вернуть.

Примеры:

```js
// Производим вычисления без returb
function withoutReturn (a, b) {
  // Результат есть, но т. к. это внутренняя переменная и её не возвращают - результат умирает с ней
  // Можно установить его во внешнюю переменную, но это фу, не надо такими быть, держите функции чистыми
  let c = a + b;
  
  // Вот это может быть тут, правда это процедура, а не функция
  document.querySelector('#test').innerHTML = "Test";
}

function withReturn (a, b) {
  let c = a + b;
  
  // Здесь мы что-то сделали и отдаём результат, т. е. смысл как функции присутствует
  return c;
}

// undefined - ожидали сложения, которое произошло, но ничего не вернулось (т. е. автоматически вернулся маркер неустановленности)
console.info(withoutReturn(5, 5));

// 10 - сложили и вернули, то, что надо
console.info(withReturn(5, 5));
```

```html
<span id='test'></span>
```

Comment: Не могли бы вы добавить сюда примеры разных вариантов, с кодом и объяснениями?

Comment: @NickVolynkin, as you wish.

Answer (score 1):

У оператора `return` два назначения.

Во-первых, - это **немедленный выход** из функции. Т.е. оператор передаёт управление коду, вызвавшему текущую функцию.

Пример:

```
function twice(a){
  if (isNaN(a)) return; // Условный выход без результата(c undefined)
  return 2*a;           // Выход с нужным результатом
  a += 5;               // Код после вызова return не может быть выполнен
}
```

Вообще говоря, выход из функции может быть осуществлён несколькими способами:

- Достижение последнего оператора (код функции попросту заканчивается, аналогично `return;` или `return undefined;`)
- Непосредственный вызов оператора `return`
- Выбрасывание ошибки, исключения (`throw 'something'`, `throw new Error('Ошибка')`)
  *В этом случае производится "разворачивание стека", мы опускаемся по стеку вызовов, пока не встретим обработчик исключений (конструкцию `try{}catch(e){}`)*

Во-вторых, - это **возврат значения**, так называемого "результата функции".

Пример:

```
function max(a, b) {
  if (a > b) return a; // Условный выход с результатом a
  return b;            // Безусловный выход с результатом b
}
```

---

***PS***: На самом деле, всё это относится ко многим языкам программирования, не только javascript.

Comment: P. S. Разве сам перевод не значит немедленный выход? :)

Comment: перевод чего? Возврат?

Comment: Даже так, наверное. Это ИМХО.